# stateId config choosing in ExtJS

Tags: extjs, extjs4, javascript-framework

Should stateId be meaningful or a random string is sufficient?
   **stateId:"gridState"**
is good but useless, can i just type 
   **stateId:"aERDRasd"**

What is your idea?
what can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value for the `stateId` config option can be any value, even a random one, provided it is unique for your ExtJS application and consistent across page/site reloads.

Answer (score 0):

don't use a random string because it could conflict with another "random" string causing you hours of debugging later on.

instead, use something that you *know* will be unique and consistent due to the coding standards you decide to follow.

for example, i use `state` followed by the `widget.alias` in camelCase instead of lowercase like this...

```
Ext.define('my.view.user.ContactList', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.GridPanel',
    alias: 'widget.contactlist',
    stateId: 'stateContactList',
    ...
```